# Row numbering with p:dataTable

Tags: mysql, jsf-2, jpa-2.0, primefaces

I have this query:

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 'no', m.title, m.author, REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(m.content, ' ', 20), '<br>', ' '), m.viewed, m.hashid FROM book m, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r WHERE m.lang = ?1 AND m.title like CONCAT('%',?2,'%') ORDER BY m.title asc
```

The `@rownum:=@rownum+1` part of the MySQL query for result numbering as Primefaces currently does not have a facility to display a numbering column.

Is there a way to show Primefaces column numbering without having to do `@rownum:=@rownum+1`?

If not, can I construct the above query using purely the CriteriaBuilder method?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I am not quite sure whether you want a "numbering column" or "column numbering". I assume the first ;-)

Can't you use `rowIndexVar`? The Primefaces doc says:

> rowIndexVar = Variable name referring to the
>   rowIndex being processed.

This works for me:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{testBean.selectOptions}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" var="item">
    <p:column headerText="#">
        #{rowIndex+1}
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Option">
        #{item}
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The +1 is for starting with number 1.

**UPDATE:**

This code produces:

[image]

Comment: No, I want a numbering column like first row is 1, second row is 2 and so on. Let me try your example above.

Comment: @user463053 Added image of html output. Is this what you are trying?

Comment: Your solution works. Thanks heap. Now I know what the rowIndexVar is used for! ;) One more thing to go: I just need to convert the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to something more simplified so I can use the CriteriaBuilder method - because I couldn't see from the JEE 6 Tutorial examples how you can define a customed SQL SELECT string for the CriteriaBuilder method.

Comment: @user463053 I recommend to start another question on this topic. I don't use CriteriaQuery API (seems to me a bit over-complicated). I use JPQL queries instead.

Comment: Yes, I'll start another post for it. I agree with you it's a bit over-complicated and too much boilerplate for even the simplest of SQL queries!

Comment: @MattHandy i tried your solution like this                   <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{gestionUtilisateurMB.selectedUserRow.dbRowIndex}" value="#{rowIndex}" /> but i always have 0 in gestionUtilisateurMB.selectedUserRow.dbRowIndex value