# get row number in primefaces datatable by clicking button in row

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

how can I get row number in Primefaces (2.2) DataTable by clicking button in some row?
I need pass this number to javascript code with prompt() function.

## 1 solution

using `WidgetVar.selection` but in this case I use manually row selection and then click button -> bad scenario.

`<p:column> 
<p:commandButton id="someButton" value="Button" 
      actionListener="#{managedBean.someEvent}" onclick="return jsMethod(widgetVar.selection)" />
</p:column>`

Thank You!

Comment: With "row number", do you mean row ID or row index? I assumed row index, but the `selection` uses row ID.

Comment: I mean row index (for example: 0,1,2 etc.) Maybe it's mistake to use 'selection' but I get correct 'ID' (0,1,2 etc.). I use this indexes to find 'hiddenInput' by Id (thank you for this article http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html) and enter comment from 'js prompt()' to server side code for appropriate object in datatable. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, that's maybe PF 2.2 specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`UIData#getRowIndex()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#getRowIndex%28%29) for this.

```html
<p:dataTable binding="#{table}" ...>
    <p:column>
        <p:commandButton ... onclick="return jsMethod(#{table.rowIndex})" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Hi. It works but with binding don't work SortBy in columns... Where is my mistake? Thank you!

Comment: It works, table must be in request-scoped bean. http://myfaces.apache.org/orchestra/myfaces-orchestra-core/component-bindings.html

Comment: Uh, no, you should not bind it to the bean, but to the view. Use exactly the code as above. Use `#{table}` and not `#{someBean.table}`.

Comment: @BalusC i'm facing the same issue so i want know,what is the type of table property in the managed bean is it an int ?

Comment: @Amira: There's no `table` property in the managed bean. The code is just complete as-is. The component is been bound into the EL scope, not to a managed bean.

Comment: get it now but in my case i want to retrieve the row number in my managed bean ,so i'll try this solution  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698513/row-numbering-with-pdatatable

Comment: your solution works well here's how i used it:         <h:commandLink action="#{gestionUtilisateurMB.showUserDetails}" value="#{userObj.name}">  
                   <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{gestionUtilisateurMB.selectedUserRow}" value="#{userObj}" />
 <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{gestionUtilisateurMB.selectedUserRow.dbRowIndex}" value="#{table.rowIndex}" />
        
                </h:commandLink>