# Number of Item in DataTable - Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

is that I have uploaded my DataTable with data from BD, but what I need is to put the row number of the loaded data in my Grid.

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="rol" value="#{mantRolMB.roles}"  
         paginator="true" rows="10"  
         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks}
         {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
         rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" rowKey="#{item}" >  

<p:column>  
    <f:facet name="header">  
        <h:outputText value="N°" />  
    </f:facet>  
    <h:outputText value="#{item}" />  
</p:column>  

<p:column>  
    <f:facet name="header">  
        <h:outputText value="Nombre Corto" />  
    </f:facet>  
    <h:outputText value="#{rol.nbNomCorto}" />  
</p:column>  

<p:column>  
    <f:facet name="header">  
        <h:outputText value="Nombre Largo" />  
    </f:facet>  
    <h:outputText value="#{rol.nbNomLargo}" />  
</p:column>  

</p:dataTable>
```

Please help to load a item number.

Comment: Do you mean like using `rowIndexVar`? Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698513/row-numbering-with-pdatatable) can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `rowIndexVar="rowIndex"` and then use it like this: `<h:outputText value="#{rowIndex}" />`